# Ruby - Undefined Local Variable or Method

Tags: ruby, function, variables

I'm trying to run a code like this:

```
class Run_Fiction_Generator < Fiction_Generator
  def generate_story
    puts "Title: \"#{generator.title} #{generator.random_date}\""
    puts "---------"
    puts generator.story
  end
end

prompt = '>'

puts "Hello Welcome to Fiction Generator"
puts "First a little about me: "
puts ""

generator = Run_Fiction_Generator.new

puts "This amazing Fiction Generator was created by: #{generator.created_by}"
puts "He's a student with ID number: #{generator.student_id} "
puts ""
puts "Okay now your story! Enter '1' if you want to generate a story now, or '2' if you don't want to"
print prompt
answer = gets.chomp

if answer == "1"
  generate_story
else
  puts "It was nice meeting you, catch ya later!"
end
```

but the method `generator_story` in the `if` statement keeps throwing this error:

> undefined local variable or method 'generate_story' for main:Object (NameError)

I'm under the impression that I already defined the method in my code. Can anyone tell where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 6):

`generate_story` is a method of `Run_Fiction_Generator` and it should be called like this:

```
generator.generate_story
```

Comment: Hi detunized, I tried your suggestion but it still didn't work. Now the errors has been thrown to the generator_story method "generator_story: undefined local variable or method 'generator' for #Run_Fiction_Generator. 

So sorry to be a bother but I'm a noob and I'm under serious pressure right now. It tooks me weeks to get this far and now I'm just frustrated

Comment: @muyiwamat, you should not use `generator.` inside `Run_Fiction_Generator` methods. `generator` is local variable defined outside of the class. It seems you're not sure what you are doing. Please first read a book on Ruby and get the basics right.

Comment: I had the same problem and I did the same I instantiated the class and called the method using the object.. it worked... I am new to Ruby coming from Java... calling a local method like this is a bit verbose... I think..

Answer (score 1):

Your other problem is how you're accessing your variables and methods inside the generate story method. Try this:

```
class Run_Fiction_Generator < Fiction_Generator
  def random_date
    "10/20/2012"
  end

  def title
   "Spooky, Late Halloween Story"
  end

  def generate_story
    puts "Title: \"#{title} #{random_date}\""
    puts "---------"
    puts @story
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. title and random_date are actually functions inherited from another class. So they're not exactly variables I created within this particular code.

Comment: Ok edited accordingly. That code works if title and random_date are instance methods and for an instance variable named @story.

Comment: So you're saying I can make instance variables of inherited functions? I'll give it a try. I'm just not sure it would work that way cos I would have to create and object of the inherited class to call it's functions Thanks

Comment: No... but if title and random_date are inherited methods, that will work.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I give up. My plan was to do this in as little number of lines of code as I can possibly can. I guess I'm just gonna have to copy and paste 
puts "Title: \"#{generator.title} #{generator.random_date}\""
puts "--------"
puts generator.story

everywhere I need it. Thanks for your time

Comment: I just made another edit with some test methods in there for title and random_date. That works. There's no reason it wouldn't be working for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

BTW: class name is "wrong"

use CamelCase for class names, not '_ to separate.